# Is there any unreachable result?

Tags: logic, infinity, proof-theory

I hope that this question is reasonable and make sense because I am not sure.

Every theorem's proof is consisting of finite logical steps.

Can a proof of the theorem require infinitely many logical steps ?

If it is so, we can not prove it right ?

Comment: *" For example, we find writers insisting, as though it were a restrictive condition, that in rigorous mathematics only a finite number of deductions are admissible in a proof — as if someone had succeeded in making an infinite number of them."* - Hilbert in [On the Infinite](https://math.dartmouth.edu/~matc/Readers/HowManyAngels/Philosophy/Philosophy.html).

Comment: Are there such theorems? I can't think of a mathematical statement that requires an infinite number of logical steps to be proven ...

Comment: Wouldn't a proof by induction require an infinite amount of steps?

Comment: @hjhjhj57 No, that's the point of the induction axiom in PA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is such a thing as *infinitary logics*, where a proof can consist of infinitely many steps, suitably arranged. But that is not really mainstream, in the sense that it is not intended to be a useful model of the ordinary mathematical reasoning that is done outside mathematical logic.

More mainstream, you may have heard of *Gödel's incompleteness theorem*, which says that if you choose some axioms to reason from in a halfway reasonable way (there's a precise technical definition of "halfway reasonable" that applies here, of course), then there will be a claim $G$ such that neither $G$ nor $\neg G$ can be proved. That does not have anything to do with "infinitely long proofs". But the theorem also comes with an argument that $G$ is actually *true*, which can be said to be an example of an "unreachable result". What actually happens, of course if that $G$ *can* be proved (in finitely many steps) if only we allow the proof to use stronger assumptions than those of the system the Incompleteness Theorem was proved for.

Answer (score 1):

By the usual definition, a proof is a finite sequence of statements in some language, where each statement is of finite length.  However, there is such a thing as
[Infinitary logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitary_logic).